# rsync from multiple sources

Tags: rsync

I have a 40G music collection that I need to sync to a server in another country.

At the moment I am rsyncing it across, however I have that same 40G collection on two machines with two internet connections.

Ideally, I'd like to start rsync from both souces to make it go twice as fast. The correct solution would be to create a torrent and then use both boxes as seeds, but the upstream end has torrent traffic blocked (and I'd rather not hack around that, the provider is doing me a favour).

Any ideas for how to accomplish this? At the moment I'm considering just dividing the remaining directories in half and specifying them all on the commandline, but that seems ugly, and I'll probably have to do this more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsync likes to copy files in the same order.  If you wanted multiple rsyncs to work in parallel the easiest approach might be to manually partition the job between two.

For example, on machine A:

```
rsync -avz foo/[A-Ga-g]* remote:foo/
```

And then, on machine B:

```
rsync -avz foo/[H-Zh-z]* remote:foo/
```

You'd want the file sets to be of comparable size.  At some point there's a diminishing return based on the available network and disk bandwidth at the target system.

Comment: While there is theoretically a bottleneck at the other end, I'm uploading from two domestic connections to a VPS with a full duplex 100M link, so I'd need way more than 2 hosts to saturate it.

Comment: What happens when a file/folder starts with a non alphabetical letter? like `!` or `Ä`. Are they not ignored?

Comment: I provided an example that might reasonably work under certain circumstances. Using my example as an example of how you might solve a problem of this nature, you may be able to solve the problem for your particular circumstances.